# MPLABX with PIC18F4550 Debug and programming are not working

Tags: pic, firmware, mplabx, configuration

First I used MikroC for PIC to modify a firmware to a PIC18F4550. I was programming the device using MPLAB IPE and the PICKit3 programmer, everything was ok. Now, I need to change to MPLABX XC8 enviroment. The compilation was successful, so, I tried to program the device using PICKit3, the following message appeared:

Programming/Verify complete

When I reset the device, nothing happened, it was as if the programming does not work. I tried to program it using MPLAB IPE, the same happened. I tried to use ICD3, the same thing happened. So, I tried to debug it, with the ICD3 and PICKit3 an the answer was always the same:

The target device is not ready for debugging. Please check your configuration bit settings and program the device before proceeding. The most common causes for this failure are oscillator and/or PGC/PGD settings.

I guess it is not a hardware issue, because I was able to program it before using the same tools. I generated the configuration bits using MPLABX and save it to an configurationBits.c file.

Does someone have a clue why it is happening ? The code of the configurationBits.c file is below:

```
// PIC18F4550 Configuration Bit Settings
// 'C' source line config statements
// CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 4 // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (Divide by 4 (16 MHz oscillator input))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC4_PLL6// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /4][96 MHz PLL Src: /6])
#pragma config USBDIV = 1 // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = HSPLL_HS // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator, PLL enabled (HSPLL))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = ON // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config BOR = ON // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled in hardware only (SBOREN is disabled))
#pragma config BORV = 3 // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = ON // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768 // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = ON // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = ON // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF // Dedicated In-Circuit Debug/Programming Port (ICPORT) Enable bit (ICPORT disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
```

*****EDITED*****

Nothing appears at LCD, it only showed dark squares. The device does not have led indicators, so I will try to add led indicators to it. But, It is strange, because I used Proteus to simulate and the code worked fine.

About the configuration bits, I thought it would be the watchdog, I tried to disable it, but this did not work. In the past, when I was implementing in mikro C, the watchdog was enabled too and it worked fine.

Comment: Does 'verify' with IPE return a success? Are these config bits all the same as set with MikroC?

Comment: @PhilG , yes. IPE return success. All config bits are the same.

Comment: If the config bits are the same then that's not the problem. "I guess it is not a hardware issue, because I was able to program it before" - if you program it with the Mikro C code again does it still work? If so there must be a problem in code you haven't shown us. If not then it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. It was in this line:

```
#pragma config LVP = ON // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
```

It needed to be OFF.

Now Below is the correct configuration bits:

```
// PIC18F4550 Configuration Bit Settings
// 'C' source line config statements
// CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 4       // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (Divide by 4 (16 MHz oscillator input))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC4_PLL6// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /4][96 MHz PLL Src: /6])
#pragma config USBDIV = 1       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator (HS))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = ON        // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config BOR = ON         // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled in hardware only (SBOREN is disabled))
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF     // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON      // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = ON      // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP disabled)
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF      // Dedicated In-Circuit Debug/Programming Port (ICPORT) Enable bit (ICPORT disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
```